# Safety check for cycling from Kerala to Jammu&Kashmir

Tags: india, bicycles, kerala

I am planning to have a journey across India (Kerala to Jammu & Kashmir) by Bicycle (About 3500 km). Is it safe to travel such a distance by cycle? Will there be any threatening situations? What are the things that I would have to take care of during this journey.

Comment: Have you ever ridden a bike on that long of journey?  Can you repair flat tires, broken cables, adjust derailleurs, etc?

Comment: thats funny.. :D Its the first time ever, but i think i can manage a flat tyre.. :D
I was asking about the other issues based on places/people/animals or climate, etc

Comment: It is a serious consideration for doing long distance tours. Being ready for that long of a ride and being able to fix your bike is far more important than the occasional animal you might come across.  Plus it will be hard to answer what you might encounter, until you detail your proposed route, as there are many possible ways to go from Kerala to Kashmir)

Comment: I would imagine anyone contemplating a 3500km bike ride, is somewhat aware of basic bike servicing!

Comment: This might be better suited for [http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/](http://bicycles.stackexchange.com/) if your question is mostly about the biking part, and not the travel part. If its about the journey, then you have to give details on your route. Keeping in mind 3500 KM is asking a lot from even the most experienced riders.

Comment: Also try asking the question a forum bcmtouring.com, as it is specific forum for people doing road trips in india, you sure will find somebody who has done something similar..